# Created some local git repos which are now non-functioning after re-installing Windows

Tags: windows, git, repository

I created these repos which worked fine then I installed Windows 8 (from Windows 8 RC), the repos were in a different hard drive so they remained.

When I try to clone the repos now I get the following error:

> git.exe clone     --progress -v  "E:\JabberRepo\broken\Jabber2"
>   "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Jabber2"
>
> Cloning into 'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Jabber2'... fatal: failed to copy
>   file to
>   'C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Jabber2/.git/objects/4b/345b002559536455b6766bc5cec27c09f661cf':
>   Permission denied fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (62 ms @ 16/12/2012 10:02:58
>   PM)

And similar 'permission denied' errors when trying to push to the local repo.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: You could try running the Command Prompt as Administrator and clone again. Then you should be able to access the files on E:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably unrelated to git, but a windows issue. Your current user does not have access to `E:\JabberRepo\broken\Jabber2`. Can you open the folder and it’s `.git` folder in explorer?

You need to change the file permissions as explained [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed).